# Formatting an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is what I want excel to do= If column F says SP then turn column M - same row - a colour if the year is less than 2011.

Answer (score 3):

Use Conditional Formatting.

[image]

Formula: `=AND($F1="SP",$M1<2011)`